# Get a record containing data from cross table relations

Tags: typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I have three database tables: `contents`, `tags`, and `content_tags_xref`.
Each record on `contents` table might have n-number of corresponding records from `tags`; the relation of each content with the tags is stored in a cross-reference table called `content_tags_xref`.

I want to get an object of `content` containing its corresponding `tags`.

**contents**

```
+----+-----------------+
| id |      title      |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | Lorem ipsum ... |
+----+-----------------+
```

**tags**

```
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
|  1 | foo   |
|  2 | bar   |
+----+-------+
```

**content_tags_xref**

```
+----+------------+--------+
| id | content_id | tag_id |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 |          1 |      1 |
|  2 |          1 |      2 |
+----+------------+--------+
```

What I want to get is something structured like the following:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Lorem ipsum ...",
    "tags": [
        { "id": 1, "title": "foo" }
        { "id": 2, "title": "bar" }
    ]
}
```

What I get from the following method is:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Lorem ipsum ..."
}
```

Here is my code:

```
findContent(content_id: number): Promise<any> {
        return this.contentRepository.createQueryBuilder('content')
            .leftJoinAndSelect(ContentTagXref, 'ctx', 'ctx.content_id = content.id')
            .leftJoinAndSelect(Tag, 'tag', 'ctx.tag_id = tag.id')
            .where('content.id = :content_id', { content_id })
            .getOne();
}
```

If I change `getOne()` with `getMany()` the result is the same as above.
If I use `getRawMany()` I will get something like this - which repeats content fields for each tag:

```
[
    {
        "content_id": 1,
        "content_title": "Lorem ipsum ...",
        "ctx_id": 1,
        "tag_id": 1,
        "tag_content": "foo",
    },
    {
        "content_id": 1,
        "content_title": "Lorem ipsum ...",
        "ctx_id": 2,
        "tag_id": 2,
        "tag_content": "bar",
    }
]
```

I have also tried adding relations in my entities using `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` decorators.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
findContent(content_id: number): Promise<any> {
  return this.contentRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('content')
    .leftJoinAndSelect(ContentTagXref, 'ctx', 'ctx.content_id = content.id')
    .leftJoinAndSelect(Tag, 'tag', 'ctx.tag_id = tag.id')
    .where('content.id = :content_id', { content_id })
    .getOne()
    .then((content) => {
      if (!content) return null;

      const { id, title } = content;
      const tags = content.ctx.map(({ tag }) => ({ id: tag.id, title: tag.title }));

      return {
        id,
        title,
        tags,
      };
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but `content` does not have `ctx` in it. thus it gives me `ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`